Number of ways a chess king can move from a1 to h8
Assume a king sits on a1 on an 8x8 chessboard. The king is restricted so he can only move up, right, or diagonally towards top-right. How many paths are there to h8. I know this is a duplicate question that has been asked once before, but no one gave a final numerical answer. I am currently getting this wrong in a course, and wanted some outside feedback. My process is as follows:

Observe that the king's number of right and upward moves are always equal
Observe that any time the king moves diagonally, it takes away one upward and one right move
So, without any diagonal moves, the king's total paths would be all permutations of 7 right moves and 7 upward moves. For 1 diagonal move, it would be 6 of each, and 1 diagonal, ....
So the solution would be as follows:
$$\frac{14!}{2*7!} + \frac{13!}{2*6!*1} + \frac{12!}{2*5!*2!} + \frac{11!}{2*4!*3!} + \frac{10!}{2*3!*4!} + \frac{9!}{2*2!*5!} + \frac{8!}{6!} + \frac{7!}{7!} = 14,122,893$$

This intuitively makes sense to me as the distinct permutations for each number of diagonal moves. It is the same as doing the permutations of "RRRRRRRUUUUUUU", "RRRRRRUUUUUUD", "RRRRRUUUUUDD", ... until you get to "DDDDDDD". Apparently this solution is wrong, but I'm missing how/why.
Duplicate Post: How many possible ways we can move a king in chessboard from 1A to 8H just using up right and diagonal move

Please link to the duplicates.

With the given restriction and the start place $a8$ , there is only one possible route. Do you mean start place $a1$ ?

Wait.... he can't move left?  in any way?  Then only one.  He's already on the rightmost column so he can't move left and he can't move anymore right so all you can do is move forward.

Sorry, meant a1, not a8. And linked the duplicate post.

Why do you say the solution is wrong?  It's the accepted answer in the dupe you link to.

Can you elaborate on how you obtained $14! / ( 2 \times 7!)$?  Note that in the linked post, it is $ 14$ / (7! \times 7!)$.

@CalvinLin good catch.  That's the error.  There are 14 moves.  Seven of them may be ups and ther rest are rights.  So it's ${14 \choose 7}=\frac {14!}{(14-7)!7!} = \frac {14!}{7!7!}$.  If imagine the OP is confusing $2* 7!$ with $(7!)^2$.

If you have $n$ moves of which $a$ are of type 1, $b$ are of type 2, and $c=n-(a+b)$ are of type 3.  Then you have $a$ out of $n$ chooses as two where to place the first, $b$ out of $n-a$ to put the second.  And the remaining $n-(a+b)=c$ must be fille with the third type.  So that as ${n\choose a}{n-a\choose b}{n-(a+b)\choose c}=\frac {n!}{a!(n-a)!}\frac {(n-a)!}{b!(n-a-b)!}\frac{(n-a-b)!}{(n-a-b)!0!} = \frac {n!}{a!b!c!}$.  So all the $\frac {k!}{2*m!*n!}$ should all be $\frac {k!}{m!m!n!}$.

You can get the number with any spreadsheet program without understanding the problem on any deep level in under a minute. Put 1 into A1, copy it to A2->A8  and into B1->H1, then put B2=A1+A1+B1 as formula, copy it to all remaining squares of the board. You will find that H8 contains the number 48639, which is your answer.

Such paths consisting of only north (N), east (E), and northeast (NE) steps are counted by the Delannoy numbers.  In particular the one you've asked for, moving seven steps north and seven steps east, happens to be $D(7,7) = 48639$.  These can be computed by a recursion $D(m, n) = D(m-1, n) + D(m-1, n-1) + D(m, n-1)$ with suitable initial conditions.
You're attempting to count them by the number of NE steps, which is a great idea!  But the number of paths with $k$ NE moves, and therefore $7-k$ N moves and $7-k$ E moves, is the multinomial coefficient
$${14-k \choose k, 7-k, 7-k} = {(14-k)! \over (7-k)!^2 k!}$$
and not what you've used,
$$(14-k)! \over 2 \times k! (7-k)! $$
In fact if you do the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^7 {(14-k)! \over (7-k)!^2 k!}$$
you'll get the right number.

The mistake here is that you replaced $7!7!$ with $2\cdot 7!$, while it is actually $(7!)^2$. Other than that the solution seems to be correct.
